# mongodb remove all dates less than specified

Tags: mongodb, date

I have the following data.

```
{
    deviceID: 186,
    date: "2014-3-15"
}
{
    deviceID: 186,
    date: "2014-3-14"
}
{
    deviceID: 186,
    date: "2014-3-13"
}
```

And some lower dates, like `2014-3-9 , 8 ,7 ,6` etc.

When doing a `db.coll.remove({date:{$lte:"2014-3-5"}})`

Mongo removes the `15,14,13` aswell, but keeps single digit day dates. Is this maybe due to the date is a string?

I dont know how else to format the date so I can remove all dates below a certain date.

It is supposed to be a cleaning process, removing all documents with a date lower than specified.

Comment: You don't need to convert the string to a date, just make sure that the day and month are always two digits, padded with a zero: `2014-03-09`. Then your queries will properly remove the naturally sorted date strings.

Answer (score 19):

Its because the date field you are querying on is a string filed and not a Date(). In your mongo documents instead of a custom date string, insert javascript date objects into date field.

like

```
{ deviceID: 186,,"date": new Date(2012, 7, 14) }
```

and when you execute the remove do it like

```
db.coll.remove({date:{$lte:new Date(2012, 7, 14)}})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove data from MongoDB from the date less than specified, you MUST make sure of the date.

Easiest way for you to check whether you are inputting the right format is to test it before you use it in your query.

For example if you want to get current date in ISODate in Mongo shell, just type `new Date` and you will get the current date in Mongo.

I've tried the following in the Mongo shell:

```
new Date(2017, 11, 1)
```

and it returns

```
ISODate("2017-11-30T16:00:00Z")
```

which is not what I wanted.

What I want is to delete data before 1 November 2017.

Here's what works for me:

```
new Date("2017-11-01")
```

and it returns:

```
ISODate("2017-11-01T00:00:00Z")
```

Which is what I wanted.

Comment: Very good call. Beware that for months and dates add additional 0 at front if 1-9. Otherwise mongodb won't be able to correctly parse it. If not sure, try and see what it returns first before putting it into a remove clause to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are storing your data in a wrong format. You have a string an string
`'15'` is smaller than string `'5'`. Convert your strings in the beginning to date (read [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#date) how to use dates in mongo).

And only than you can use it to properly compare your dates:

```
db.coll.remove({
  date:{
    $lte : new Date(2012, 7, 14)
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I think new Date(2012, 7, 14) is inaccurate, at least the moment when I tested it. I've wrote what I did in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47170066/2065804

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is is your dates are **strings**.

So in a lexical sense when comparing strings "2014-3-5" **is** greater than "2014-3-15", as what is being compared is that "1" is less than "5".

Fix your dates as real ISO Dates, or you will forever have this problem.

Batch convert like this, assuming "year" "month" "day" in format:

```js
db.eval(function(){

   db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
       var d = doc.date.split("-");
       var date = new Date( 
           "" + d[0] + "-" +
          ( d[1] <= 9 ) ? "0" + d[1] : d[1] + "-" +
          ( d[2] <= 9 ) ? "0" + d[2] : d[2]
       );
       db.collection.update(
           { "_id": doc._id },
           { "$set": { "date": date }
       );
   });
})
```

That makes sure you get the right dates on conversion.