# How can delete the specific data between two specific dates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a DB table in MongoDB called users. I would like to delete the between two specific dates. like  Oct 15 2019 to June 1st 2020 is there any way to delete the specific data created between the dates.

Data Structure like this:-

```
{
    username: demo1,
    createdate: "2019-10-15"
},
{
    username: demo2,
    createdate: "2020-01-15"
},
{
    username: demo2,
    createdate: "2020-05-01"
}
```

Comment: Please share what your sample collection looks like? What you have tried? What was the result of the query and what is your expected result?

Comment: @palaѕн  
`{
    username: demo1,
    createdate: "2019-10-15"
},
{
    username: demo2,
    createdate: "2020-01-15"
},
{
    username: demo2,
    createdate: "2020-05-01"
}`

Comment: the table is user and i want to delete the createdate: "2019-10-15" date to createdate: "2020-05-01" all the entered record in data base.

Comment: Is createdate is a ISODate field or just a string here?

Comment: Also, check this if it is a string field: [mongodb remove all dates less than specified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22422178)