# Mongo db query for getting records of and delete 2018

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using below query to find records for 2018. my query is to find first 2018 records and then delete
2018 records. can i delete from GUI Robo3t?

```
db.transaction.find().sort({timeStamp:1}).limit(5000);
```

sample document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 999999001, 
    "eventId" : "LAS071", 
    "eventName" : "YouRefer", 
    "timeStamp" : "2018-06-17T17:12:55.254Z", 
    "eventMethod" : "Reporting", 
    "resourceName" : "AddSTB", 
    "targetType" : "", 
    "resourseUrl" : "", 
    "operationName" : "", 
    "functionStatus" : "", 
    "pageId" : "CloseJobView", 
    "ban" : 144235039, 
    "jobId" : 139980225, 
    "wrid" : 139980225, 
    "jobType" : "MRJ2IX", 
    "Uid" : "kt7201", 
    "techRegion" : "SE", 
    "mgmtReportingFunction" : "N", 
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y" 
}
```

I used the query and getting in finding records:

```
db.transaction.deleteMany({
  "timeStamp": { $gte: new Date(2018, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2019, 0, 1) }
})
```

but i have around 100k records of 2018. How can we use above query for deletion of 5K records at a time?

I tried with finding first in collection, but it's saying 0 records fetched.

```
db.transaction.find({
  "timeStamp": { $gte: new Date(2018, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2019, 0, 1) }
})

Output: Fetched 0 record(s) in 31ms
```

But i checked in collection below records with these timestamp are present,

```
"timeStamp" : ISODate("2018-12-31T18:30:03.379Z"),

"timeStamp" : ISODate("2018-12-31T18:30:03.982Z"),
```

Comment: need to delete 5000 records of 2018.

Comment: Sample document?

Comment: {
    "_id" : 999999001,
    "eventId" : "LAS071",
    "eventName" : "YouRefer",
    "timeStamp" : "2018-06-17T17:12:55.254Z",
    "eventMethod" : "Reporting",
    "resourceName" : "AddSTB",
    "targetType" : "",
    "resourseUrl" : "",
    "operationName" : "",
    "functionStatus" : "",
    "pageId" : "CloseJobView",
    "ban" : 144235039,
    "jobId" : 139980225,
    "wrid" : 139980225,
    "jobType" : "MRJ2IX",
    "Uid" : "kt7201",
    "techRegion" : "SE",
    "mgmtReportingFunction" : "N",
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y"
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22422237/9450155  i think this useful for you.

Comment: need to delete the records from collection above having timestamp containing 2018:  "timeStamp" : "2018-.......  also in collection having records 2019 and 2020 wnt to kwwp only 2019 and 2020 records in colection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a shell command to delete all documents from the year 2018:

```
db.transaction.deleteMany({
  "timeStamp": { $gte: new Date(2018, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2019, 0, 1) }
})
```

It works by querying for all records with a `timeStamp` greater than or equal to January 1st 2018, and with a `timeStamp` less than January 1st 2019.

**Edit**

Your `timeStamp` field seems to be a string. Try using this query that looks for the string 2018:

```
{ "timeStamp": { $regex: "^2018" } }
```

Comment: db.transactions.find({
  "timeStamp": { $gte: new Date(2018, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2019, 0, 1) }
})

Fetched 0 record(s) in 13161ms  ... tried with above query to find first 0 records found.. thanks experts please suggest.

Comment: yes experts, thanks it's working, if in collection having more then 30K records of 2018 can we delete in batches to overcome load.

Comment: Also experts, i need an help to find the duplicate records from collections, and delete those duplicate records, i need to make one new collection, insert duplicate records and delete the duplicates from collection, how can it be achievable.

Comment: Thanks experts, , also if we have to delete around 5K records at once from above query for 2018 date how can we write the above script, pls suggest. –

Comment: Have you tried using [deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/)?

Comment: Thanks experts i tried running: 
db.transactions.deleteMany({
  "timeStamp": { $gte: new Date(2018, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2019, 0, 1) }
}).limit (5000);
Getting below error:

Error:
TypeError: db.transactions.deleteMany(...).limit is not a function 
Details:
@(shell):1:1

Comment: Because your timeStamp field is not a Date you have to use the second filter. The amount of documents deleted by `deleteMany()` cannot be limited. If you don't want to delete all the documents at once, you will have to pass a more specific filter.

Comment: Thanks experts, can you please provide for deletion of 5000 records at a time, once.

Comment: Thanks experts, can you please provide for deletion of 5000 records  from above script.

Comment: Hi Experts, can you  suggest i have edited the findigs.